# Code having a value error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help with my code that keeps giving me this error.
The error is:

`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

The line that gave me the error is this line:

`question , answer = generateQuestions (maxNum)`

I can't figure out how to fix it. Below is my code :

```
 import random

    def generateQuestions ( maxNum ) :
      ops = ['+','-']
      var1 = random.randrange ( maxNum ) 
      var2 = random.randrange ( maxNum )
      maxNum += 1
      operation = random.choice (ops)
      ques = 'What is' + str(var1) + operation + str(var2) + '?'
      if operation == '+' :
        var1 + var2
      else :
        var1 - var2
      return ques

    difficulty = 0 
    lives = 0
    numofquestion = 0
    correctCount = 0
    while int (difficulty) <= int (0) or int(difficulty) >= int(4) :
        print ('Welcome to the Math Tester')
        print ('Please choose your difficulty')
        difficulty = int (input ( '"1" for Easy \n"2" for Medium \n"3" for Hard\n'))

        if difficulty == 1 :
            print ('Easy Selected, You Have 3 Lives')
            lives , maxNum = 3,10

        elif difficulty == 2 :
            print ('Medium Selected, You Have 2 Lives')
            lives , maxNum = 2,25

        elif difficulty == 3 :
            print ('Hard Selected, You Have 1 Life')
            lives , maxNum = 1,50
        for numofquestion in range (10) :

            print ( 'Question', numofquestion + 1, 'of 10,',lives ,'lives remaining.')
            question , answer = generateQuestions (maxNum)

            print ( question)
            userAns = int (input ())

            if answer == userAns :
                print ('Correct!')
                correctCount += 1

            else :
                print ('Incorrect!')
                lives -= 1


        print ('Result :')
        print ('You scored {} / 10.'.format (correctCount))
        print ('{} % - You {}!' .format (( correctCount / 10)*100, 'pass' if correctCount > 4 else 'fail'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you are only returning the question from your function, although you are expecting it to also return an answer. The following change to your function should work:

```
def generateQuestions ( maxNum ) :
    ops = ['+','-']
    var1 = random.randrange ( maxNum ) 
    var2 = random.randrange ( maxNum )
    maxNum += 1
    operation = random.choice (ops)
    ques = 'What is' + str(var1) + operation + str(var2) + '?'
    if operation == '+' :
        answer = var1 + var2
    else :
        answer = var1 - var2

    return ques, answer
```

Comment: As I mention in my answer, it's best not to give actual solutions to homework questions.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Sorry for  the troubles i have with my homework.

Answer (score 0):

Your `generateQuestions` function does not return both the question and answer: it just returns the question. You do calculate the answer in that function, but you don't even save it in a variable, let alone return it.

You'll need to store that calculation and return it alongside `ques`.

(I purposely haven't given you the actual code, since this is obviously homework.)

Comment: Thanks for explaining the error for me.  Your explanation helped me.